# Scala MongoDB Driver does not find Objects

Tags: mongodb, scala

In my Scala Application, I am trying to `find()` all Objects for a List of `ObjectId`s.
My DB Structure looks like that:

```
case class Parent(_id: ObjectId, name: String)
case class Child(_id: ObjectId, name: String, parents: List[ObjectId])
```

Now, I have a list of ParentIds and want to find all `Parents.find(in("_id", foundChild.parents))`.

Unfortunately, `parents` will be empty. I have searched the Internet for a `in("_id", List[ObjectId])`-Example, but couldn't find a single one.

Reading the [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/1.0/builders/filters/), it seems like it is not supported to check for lists, but only for `TItem*`. Is it possible to achieve a "is in List" Check somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass in the `List` as varargs:

```
Parents.find(in("_id", foundChild.parents: _*))
```

Comment: ah i knew i could parse it somehow, but i have never done it until now. thanks.